# How to pass an array prop parent to child though an interface (React Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router, react-props

I have a child component (Gallery) that needs an array (posts) from its parent (Homepage). I tried through an interface (GalleryProps) but it's not working.

```
interface IPost {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    author: string;
    content: string;
}

interface GalleryProps {
    posts: (IPost[]) => void;
}

const Gallery: React.FC<GalleryProps> = (props) => {
    return (
        {posts={props.posts}.map(post =>.map(post =>
            <div className="postCard" key={post.id}>
                <Link className="cardLink" to ={ `/detail/${post.id}`}>
                    <div>
                        {post.title}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {post.author}
                    </div>
                </Link>
            </div>
        )}
    );
};

const Homepage: React.FC = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState<IPost[]>([]);
    let navigateNew = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        getPosts()
            .then(items => {
                setPosts(items)
            })
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="containerHomepage">
                <Gallery
                    posts={posts}
                />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Homepage;
```

I think the problem is in GalleryProps. Do I have the array declaration wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this data you are having in props of Gallery is in the array , you can write it like below

```
interface IPost {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    author: string;
    content: string;
}


interface GalleryProps {
  posts: IPost[];
}


const Gallery: React.FC<GalleryProps> = ({posts}) => {
  return (
        posts.map(post => {
          return (
            <div className="postCard" key={post.id}>
                <Link className="cardLink" to ={ `/detail/${post.id}`}>
                    <div>
                        {post.title}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {post.author}
                    </div>
                </Link>
            </div>          
          )
        })
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks! With your code i got this error:Type '({ posts }: PropsWithChildren<GalleryProps>) => Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FC<GalleryProps>'.
  Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2322)

Comment: It's because the structure of the object literals don't match the Assignment structure. Means posts you are sending in from Gallery Component should be in array with Types exactly same as of IPost
[check out this fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-9m20bv?file=/src/App.tsx)